# Writing list with criteria 1 line - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get better at writing more 'clean' and/or elegant code. I have seen examples around but I can't make them work for this particular example. Logic is very simple and I'm hoping that with some pointers on punctuation or syntax I can pick up the habit.

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
elist = []

evenlist = [i for i in a if a % 2 == 0]
print(evenlist)
```

I have only been able to make this work on the longer format here below:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
elist = []


for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        elist.append(i)

print(elist)
```

Comment: First code has `a % 2` while the second one has `i % 2`

Comment: replace `a % 2` with `i % 2`

Answer (score 2):

Should be this:

```
evenlist = [i for i in a if i % 2 == 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
evenlist = [i for i in a if a % 2 == 0]
#                           ^
#                         Hmmm!
```

You probably wat to be checking `i` (an element) for evenness, rather than `a` (the entire list). Checking a list for evenness doesn't make much sense unless there's some magic happening in the background that ensures every element in the list is even. But there's not:

```
>>> [1,2,3] % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

---

As an aside, there's *another* way to do this, specifically:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, a))
```

I think this is less readable myself but I suspect it may be more space-efficient if you just want to *process* them rather than create a list from them:

```
for item in filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, a):
    do_something_with(item)
```

That doesn't create a whole new list, instead simply retrieving values from the existing list that match the filter criteria. Probably won't matter unless your lists tend to get large.